# Why does the count of an ADODB count result display differently on Virt. Dedic. Hosted site differently than other sites I've worked with?

Tags: php, sql, adodb

When not using symfony, I use adodb for querying databases. I have all of the queries that would be executed in a file. Each select statement is accompanied with its select count statement and am using binding parameters. So I make sure there is a count and if the count is zero, the appropriate error message is displayed. If there is a count greater than zero, then the select statement is performed. On my hosting and other shared hosting sites, the select count gives me a value and I use substr to get the count, but on my client's virtual dedicated server w/plesk, something weird happens. Here is an Example below:

```
$selectcountsql = "select count(*) from thistable where email = ? and pwdhash = ?";
$selectcountquery = $db->Execute($selectcountsql,array($email,$pwdmashed));
$count = substr($selectcountquery,10);
```

On other clients' sites w/shared hosting, the output of $count is an integer that is the actual count of records. 
However, on my client's site hosted on Virtual Dedicated Hosting, when I:

1. echo the $selectcountquery variable, it displays the value as COUNT(*) 1 --e.g. if count of 1 record returned.
2. echo the $count variable, it displays nothing.
3. when I chance $count to be substr($selectcountquery,5) , and echo it I get the word: Object
4. when I print_r or dump the values of $selectcountquery, I get an array of many adodb variables.

Do you have an idea as to what may be happening?

Comment: Is there a difference between the versions of PHP, Adodb or MySQL on the vds compared to your local/development server?

Comment: I don't think so. But thanks for that ?/advice.

Answer (score 1):

On his server, I ended up changing it to the way the adodb manual says to do it and as a result was able to eliminate all of the select count queries in the queries file:

```
$selectsql = "select * from thistable where email = ? and pwdhash = ?";
$selectquery = $db->Execute($selectsql,array($email,$pwdmashed));
$count = $selectquery->RecordCount();
```

And everything works fine now.